# what do 形 and 便 mean and how can they combine to make the meaning “situation”?

Tags: meaning, hanja, word-origin

The Chinese word of 형편 (situation) in Korean is 形便. Can anyone explain what 形 and 便 mean and how can they combine to make the meaning "situation"?

Comment: Thank you for shifting your question here. 形便 doesn't really mean "situation" in Chinese, and it would be better to ask the meaning of Korean words at Korean SE. FYI, 形便 means *improvements* or *opportunity for improvements in one's situation* (形勢 + 便利) in Chinese, so its usage in Korean must be some kind of semantic extension.

Comment: @dROOOze thank you. I just found the answer here. 
http://kid.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2018/11/13/2018111302543.html

Comment: There is a paid Android app called [우리말 속뜻사전](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbhedu.kcmdic). It will show the same meaning of 형편 and also help you a lot for other Korean words as well. // There is a [list](https://namu.wiki/w/%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%8B%9D%20%ED%95%9C%EC%9E%90%EC%96%B4) of some Korean own Hanja words.

Comment: @Klmo I just purchased the app several days ago after seeing the ads.

Answer (score 1):

形 directly means shape(형태) <- "external" situation

便 directly means relax(편하다) <- "internal(emotional)" situation

So, 형편 means (my) (internal **or** external) situation.

In Korean, situation(상황) very similar to status(상태).